# Why is this Int32 sum always returning 0?

Tags: .net, integer

I know at least one value is not zero and sum is still always 0
Why?

```
get 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ILockSumN");
    Debug.WriteLine(iLocks[2, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[2, 1]);
    Debug.WriteLine(iLocks[3, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[3, 1]);
    Debug.WriteLine(iLocks[6, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[6, 1]);
    Int32 sum =
        iLocks[1, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[1, 1] +
        iLocks[2, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[2, 1] +
        iLocks[3, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[3, 1] +
        iLocks[4, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[4, 1] +
        iLocks[5, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[5, 1] +
        iLocks[6, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[6, 1];
    Debug.WriteLine(sum);
    return sum; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a precedence problem - basically if `iLocks[1, 1]` is `null` then it takes `0` otherwise it uses the other branch which has all the additions.

Try adding parentheses:

```
Int32 sum =
    (iLocks[1, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[1, 1]) +
    (iLocks[2, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[2, 1]) +
    (iLocks[3, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[3, 1]) +
    (iLocks[4, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[4, 1]) +
    (iLocks[5, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[5, 1]) +
    (iLocks[6, 1] == (Int32?)null ? 0 : (Int32)iLocks[6, 1]);
```

[7.12 Conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691313(v=vs.71).aspx) says:

> The conditional operator is right-associative, meaning that operations are grouped from right to left. For example, an expression of the form a ? b : c ? d : e is evaluated as a ? b : (c ? d : e).

Comment: I just figured that out on my own.  I need to wait 7 minutes to accept.

Answer (score 2):

Academic LINQ example:

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(int j, T[,] array)
{
    var length = array.GetLength(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        yield return array[i, j];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var sum = GetItems(1, iLocks)
    .Where(i => i != null)
    .Sum() ?? 0;
```

Comment: Sweet syntax - 3 more to go

Answer (score 2):

The [null coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator will work too, after adding parentheses (as noted by Michael):

```
Int32 sum =
    (iLocks[1, 1] ?? 0) +
    (iLocks[2, 1] ?? 0) +
    (iLocks[3, 1] ?? 0) +
    (iLocks[4, 1] ?? 0) +
    (iLocks[5, 1] ?? 0) +
    (iLocks[6, 1] ?? 0);
```

Or, just for kicks, combining with LINQ:

```
Int32 sum = Enumerable.Range(1,6).Select(i => iLocks[i,1] ?? 0).Sum();
```